# 401 unauthorized when connecting from outside

Tags: authorization

I've set up a SharePoint Server 2013 on Virtual Machine. When I am connected to this machine with Remote Desktop and navigate to my SP site with browser, I get to log in without problems. 
But when I navigate to this site from another computer, after logging in with my username and password, I get `401 UNAUTHORIZED`. My site uses Windows Authentication.

Are there any configuration settings, that I may have missed, that prevent me from accessing this site from outside world?

Comment: outside world means outside domain? or within the domain but different machine? Also, check VM settings - what network is it using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel almost stupid, but the thing I was looking for is...
**Alternate Access Mappings**.

Need to go to Central Admin > Application Management > Alternate Access Mappings > Edit Public URLs and add my full server name to Internet zone.

Comment: Would plz provide screen shots? Not working for me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Click Edit Public URLS

Default:  Local url 
Internet:  Url used to access publicly